# Calculate time taken to Navigating between one Screen to other Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode9, uiviewcontentmode

All,

In my project, we have some time delay (Performance) issue when Navigating from one Screen to another screen. 
Do we have any tool in Xcode to figure out which method is exactly causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can check by using Instrumentation...Here you can check which method is causing memory leaks and causing delay.

Answer (score 0):

@kiri

please check that there should not be much operations following on `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods. If you have much operation in these methods it will block `mainThread` and hence will cause delay in navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Time Profiler Instrument can show you which method takes how much time.

Hit Product -> Profile, then choose "Time Profiler".